# Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library javax.servlet.jar

Tags: java, servlets

I am getting : 
Access restriction on class due to restriction on required library javax.servlet.jar
How to solve?

Comment: What IDE are you using? What JRE?

Answer (score 0):

Thought of sharing the answer:

- Go to Project properties > Libraries tab.
- Select JRE system library > Edit.
- Here, "Execution environment" is selected.
- Select the "Alternate JRE" > click Finish.

Now the compile error will go away.